# Python RegEx- hangman algorithm

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, dictionary

I am trying to write a hangman algorithm.  My idea for it goes like this:

- Pre-process a dictionary that contains the relative letter frequencies of words depending on their length.  Step complete.

Example:

```
#Each key corresponds to length of the word.   

frequencyDict = {2: ['a', 'o', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'h', 'n', 'u', 's', 't', 'y', 'b', 'd', 'l', 'p', 'x', 'f', 'r', 'w', 'g', 'k', 'j'], 
  3: ['a', 'e', 'o', 'i', 't', 's', 'u', 'p', 'r', 'n', 'd', 'b', 'm', 'g', 'y', 'l', 'h', 'w', 'f', 'c', 'k', 'x', 'v', 'j', 'z', 'q'], 
  4: ['e', 'a', 's', 'o', 'i', 'l', 'r', 't', 'n', 'u', 'd', 'p', 'm', 'h', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'k', 'y', 'f', 'w', 'v', 'j', 'z', 'x', 'q'],
  5: ['s', 'e', 'a', 'o', 'r', 'i', 'l', 't', 'n', 'd', 'u', 'c', 'p', 'y', 'm', 'h', 'g', 'b', 'k', 'f', 'w', 'v', 'z', 'x', 'j', 'q'],
  6: ['e', 's', 'a', 'r', 'i', 'o', 'l', 'n', 't', 'd', 'u', 'c', 'p', 'm', 'g', 'h', 'b', 'y', 'f', 'k', 'w', 'v', 'z', 'x', 'j', 'q'],
  7: ['e', 's', 'a', 'i', 'r', 'n', 'o', 't', 'l', 'd', 'u', 'c', 'g', 'p', 'm', 'h', 'b', 'y', 'f', 'k', 'w', 'v', 'z', 'x', 'j', 'q'],
  8: ['e', 's', 'i', 'a', 'r', 'n', 'o', 't', 'l', 'd', 'c', 'u', 'g', 'p', 'm', 'h', 'b', 'y', 'f', 'k', 'w', 'v', 'z', 'x', 'q', 'j']}
```

I also have a generator of words in a dictionary:

```
dictionary = word_reader('C:\\Python27\\dictionary.txt', len(letters))
```

Which is based on this function

```
#Strips dictionary of words that are too big or too small from the list
def word_reader(filename, L):
  L2 = L+2
  return (word.strip() for word in open(filename) \
          if len(word) < L2 and len(word) > 2)
```

- This particular game will give you the last vowel for free.  If the word was earthen, for example, 
  the user would be given the following board: e----e- to guess.  So, I want to find a way to create a new generator or list
  with all the words stripped out of it that do not conform to the e----e- template.

`p = re.compile('^e\D\D\D\De\D$', re.IGNORECASE)` will do it, but it might find words
that contain 'e's in other places besides the first letter and second to last letter.

So my first question is:

1. How do I ensure that an 'e' is
   located ONLY in the first and the
   second-to-last position
2. How do I do create an intelligent function that will have a new regex as the puzzle updates and the computer keeps making its guesses?

For example, if the word is monkey, the computer would just be given ----e-
The first step would be for it to strip from its dictionary all words that are not 6 letters, and all words that do not conform perfectly to the '----e-' template and put that in a newList.  **How do
I go about doing this?**

It then computes a NEW frequencyDict based on the relative frequency of words that are in its
newList.

My current method of doing this looks like this:

```
   cnt = Counter()
   for words in dictionary:
      for letters in words:
         cnt[letters]+=1
```

Is this the most efficient way?

It would then use the newfrequencyDict to guess the most common letter, assuming it has
not already been guessed.  It continues to do this until (hopefully) the word is guessed.

Is this an efficient algorithm?  Are there better implementations?

Comment: This sounds like a hangman solver program rather than a hangman program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing particularly magical about regexes, and matching them against your whole dictionary is still going to take O(n) time. I'd recommend writing your own function that determines if a word is a match for a template, and running your dictionary-so-far through that.

Here's an example function:

```
def matches_template(word, template):
  found_chars = set(x for x in template if x != '-')
  for char, template_char in zip(word, template):
    if template_char == '-':
      if char in found_chars: return False
    else:
      if template_char != char: return False
  return True
```

As far as determining the next character to guess, you probably don't want to select the most frequent character. Instead, you want to select the character that comes closest to being in 50% of words, meaning you eliminate the most possibilities either way. Even that isn't optimal - it could be that certain characters are more likely to occur twice in the word, and therefore eliminate a larger proportion of candidates - but it's closer.

Comment: It depends on the rules if it is best to select the most likely character or to select the char that splits the remaining part in halves. The first strategy it relevant if a correct guess gives the player an extra guess for free. The second strategy is good for determining the correct words as fast as possible even if it is one of the other players who wins.

Comment: @Midtiby-- you are correct in that the game works like that.  However, Nick-- you bring up a good point.  How would you go about finding which character comes closest to 50% of words?

Comment: @Parseltongue Count the number of words each character occurs in, subtract half the number of remaining words from each count, and select the one with the smallest absolute value.

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up making this the correct answer to my question because the function works perfectly.  I'm just confused as to how it works.   Do you mind explaining?

Comment: @Parseltongue It iterates through the candidate word and the 'template' in lockstep. For each character, if the template contains '-' (eg, we don't know what it is), it verifies that the character in the word is not any of those already discovered. If the template character is anything else, it verifies that it matches the character in the word. To match, every check must pass.

Answer (score 3):

That's quite a lot of questions. I'll try to answer a few.

1. Your regex should look more like this: '`^e[^e][^e][^e][^e]e[^e]$`'. Those `[^e]` bits say "match any character that is not 'e'. Note that unlike your regex, this *will* mach non-letter characters, but that shouldn't be a problem if you make sure your dictionary has only letters. Note that once you have uncovered more than one letter, you would put all the letters into each of those "don't match" sections. For example, say that the 'a' is guessed, so it's "ea---e-", now you will match with the regex '`^ea[^ae][^ae][^ae]e[^ae]$`'.
2. You could simply write a function that takes a string such as "ea---e-" and builds a regex from it. It would simply need to a) find all of the non-hyphen letters in the string, as a set (in this case, `{'a', 'e'}`), b) flatten the set into a "match-all-but-this" regex fragment (`[^ae]`) -- note that the order is not important which is why I used a set, c) substitute each hyphen with one of those (`ea[^ae][^ae][^ae]e[^ae]`), and d) finally just put a '`^`' at the front and '`$`' at the end.
3. Lastly with the frequency dict -- well that is a very separate question. It's hard to get more efficient than a linear search through the whole dictionary. One suggestion I would make is that you possibly shouldn't be counting letters multiple times. For example, do you want the word "earthen" to contribute 2 points towards the letter count for 'e'? I would guess in Hangman that you only want it to count once, since the word "eeeeeeee" and the word "the" both have the same outcome for guessing the letter 'e' (success). But I could be wrong.

Comment: Number 3 brings up an interesting point-- How would I prevent it from double counting, on would this adversely affect the winning efficacy of the algorithm?  

As for 2, what would an example function look like?  I'm having a hard time visualizing a functional regex.

Comment: If you wanted to prevent it from double-counting, you could simply throw the word into a set. `set("earthen")` gives `set(['a', 'e', 'h', 'n', 'r', 't'])`. Then use each letter of the set to count towards the frequencies. I don't know what you mean by "an example function" or a "functional regex". I literally mean you would write a function `build_regex_matching("ea---e-")` which returns `"^ea[^ae][^ae][^ae]e[^ae]$"` using the algorithm given above.